# Meteor deploy error (mup): pushing meteor app bundle to server failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, deployment, mup

I am trying to deploy a meteor app to an AWS server, but am getting this message:

```
Started TaskList: Configuring App
[52.41.84.125] - Pushing the Startup Script
nodemiral:sess:52.41.84.125 copy file - src: /    

Users/Olivia/.nvm/versions/node/v7.8.0/lib/node_modules/mup/lib/modules/meteor/assets/templates/start.sh, dest: /opt/CanDu/config/start.sh, vars: {"appName":"CanDu","useLocalMongo":0,"port":80,"bind":"0.0.0.0","logConfig":{"opts":{"max-size":"100m","max-file":10}},"docker":{"image":"abernix/meteord:base","imageFrontendServer":"meteorhacks/mup-frontend-server","imagePort":80},"nginxClientUploadLimit":"10M"} +0ms
[52.41.84.125] x Pushing the Startup Script: FAILED  Failure
```

Previously I had been able to deploy using mup, but now I am getting this message. The only major thing I've changed is the Python path in my .noderc. I am also able to SSH into my amazon server directly from the terminal.  My mup file is:

```
module.exports = {
servers: {
one: {
  host: '##.##.##.###',
  username: 'ec2-user',
  pem: '/Users/Olivia/.ssh/oz-pair.pem'
  // password:
  // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
}}meteor: {
name: 'CanDu',
path: '/Users/Olivia/repos/bene_candu_v2',
servers: {
  one: {}
},
buildOptions: {
  serverOnly: true,
  mobileSettings: {
    public: {
      "astronomer": {
        "appId": "<key>",
        "disableUserTracking": false,
        "disableRouteTracking": false,
        "disableMethodTracking": false
      },
      "googleMaps": "<key>",
      "facebook":{
        "permissions":["email","public_profile","user_friends"]
      }
    },
  },
},
env: {
  ROOT_URL: 'http://ec2-##-##-##-###.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
  MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://. . . "
},
/*ssl: {
    crt: '/opt/keys/server.crt', // this is a bundle of certificates
    key: '/opt/keys/server.key', // this is the private key of the certificate
    port: 443, // 443 is the default value and it's the standard HTTPS port
    upload: false
},*/
docker: {
  image: 'abernix/meteord:base'
},
deployCheckWaitTime: 60
```

}
};

And I have checked to make sure there are no trailing commas, and have tried increasing the wait time.  etc. The error message I'm getting is pretty unhelpful.  Does anyone have any insight? Thank you so much!